# What to call a collection of planets?

Tags: nouns

I'm developing a small space game where players can colonise and own multiple planets.
How would I refer to something that represents a group/collection of planets?

Comment: ...........a suite

Comment: Very funny - Gustav Holst would be amused I am sure.

Comment: So are you going to tell us what the name of your game is or will be?

Comment: I'll update this post once a final name for the game will be decided!

Comment: ukliviu, it is more natural to ask questions like this with the wording "What to call". Saying "How to call" is unnatural and not really used by native speakers.

Comment: @ukliviu it's been 10 months. Got a game name yet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depending on how you wanted to go, I would suggest either "system" or "federation"

- A "System" of planets brings to mind a solar system.  While these aren't necessarily orbiting the same star, they are in the "political orbit" of another, and the analogy would be clear.
- A "federation" of planets would probably bring to mind Star Trek for some, but likewise, the intent would be clear.
- Finally an "Empire" would suggest total domination and subjugation. As such, while the analogy would be clear, it may be harsher than desired.

Comment: I see that you've taken the political as opposed to the astronomical view, which was mine.  Probably closer to what he meant.

Comment: Not a "cosmos" or a "galaxy"?

Answer (score 7):

In the context of a space game, with its sci-fi implications, the common way to refer to a collection of planets in association with their star is:  Stellar system.

"Solar System" has a specific accepted instance, which is to say the collection of planets associated with the star named "Sol", called "The Sun" in common parlance.

ETA: in light of what @AffableGeek has written, I see that I probably missed the questioner's intent.  So let me add:

Confederation

Comment: [Stellar system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_system) brings to my mind a group of stars not planets. +1 for confederation though.

Comment: I see that Wikipedia agrees with you, @terdon. Maybe I've been on the wrong side of the language all these years on *stellar system*.  It just seemed to me that the correct parallel to "solar system" is "star system" or "stellar system".  On the other hand, what would one do about a system of stars?  Perhaps planetary system is the best choice, over stellar system in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Though it might not suit your audience, [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aGlossary_of_collective_nouns_by_subject) informs me that it is:

> A quincunx of planets

Comment: Though, this also tells you to use "A consternation of mothers". What if some of the mothers are not consternate?

Comment: What if not all of my arrows are quivering? It's still a quiver of arrows :P Lots of collective nouns are unusual.

Comment: Wiktionary is not right here. A quincunx of planets is not a group of planets, but any number of planets that are in a geometric relation of 150 degrees (five Zodiacs, hence why it's called a quincunx) to each other. It does require more than one planet to be included, true; but it is not simply a generic collective noun for planets.

Comment: @skymninge: I've yet to meet a mother whose off-spring didn't consternate her at some point. Insanity is hereditary: you get it from your kids. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want something implying a physical grouping but not a ("solar"- or planetary-)system, how about *cluster*?

There are plenty of political words (*federation* & *empire* have already been suggested) such as *commonwealth*, *colony* (though you may be using that in another sense), *union*, *alliance*.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the word *domain* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/domain_1?q=domain . This word has been used in sci-fi to refer to multiple planets and/or moons that were conquered and ruled by someone.

You could also use the word *territory*.